# Bash convert single quoted var to double quoted

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have a scala project, which defines its version in build.sbt file.

I want to extract that version in a bash script to use it to build a path of a jar file, which I then want to upload to S3.

The aws s3 cp command doesn't work, though. I figured out that it doesn't work when the path is surrounded with single quotes, but it does work when the path is without any quotes. For instance:

```
aws s3 cp '<path_to_the_jar>' 's3://<bucket>/<folder>/jar_file'
```

but it works without the single quotes around the paths:

```
aws s3 cp <path_to_the_jar> s3://<bucket>/<folder>/jar_file
```

The way I am doing it:

```
~ sbt version
```

produces

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/myuser/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/myuser/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/myuser/IdeaProjects/MY-PROJECT
[info] Updating {file:/Users/myuser/IdeaProjects/MY-PROJECT
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to MY-PROJECT-build (in build file:/Users/myuser/IdeaProjects/MY-PROJECT)
[info] MY-PROJECT-bindings/*:version
[info]  0.0.0
[info] MY-PROJECT/*:version
[info]  0.0.0
[info] {.}/*:version
[info]  0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I process that with `sed`, which gives me the desired version:

```
~ sed -n "/MY-PROJECT\/\*:version/{n;p;}" | cut -f 2
0.0.0
```

The entire script:

```
script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -x
example="MY-PROEJCT"
s3_bucket="BUCKET"
s3_folder="TEST"

# problematic variable, gets set to ‘0.0.0’ instead of just 0.0.0
version=$(sbt version | sed -n "/MY-PROJECT\/\*:version/{n;p;}" | cut -f 2)

# Builds the jar file locally
~ sbt assembly

# The command is expanded to: JAR_S3_PATH='s3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jar'
JAR_S3_PATH=s3://$s3_bucket/$s3_folder/$example-test-$version.jar

echo $example
echo $version
echo $JAR_S3_PATH

# The command is expanded to: aws s3 cp '/target/scala-2.11/MY-PROJECT-test-assembly-0.0.0.jar' 's3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jar'
aws s3 cp /target/scala-2.11/$example-test-assembly-$version.jar ${JAR_S3_PATH}
```

The final `aws s3 cp` command doesn't work. Strangely, if I just copy paste it into the terminal it does work, but it doesn't in the script.

1. Why it doesn't work with the single quotes?
2. How can I convert a single with quote variables to a one with double quotes?

I did look into topics about the difference between single quotes and double quotes in bash, but still I don't know how that applies to my problem.

**EDIT**

None of the variables contains quotes when I print them with `echo`. However, the option `set -x` is set for this script and it prints everything that is done by the script. Look at this please:

```
+ echo MY-PROJECT 
MY-PROJECT 
+ echo '0.0.0' 
0.0.0 
+ echo 's3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jar' 
s3://here-avf-shared/emr_test/tiledgeo-validator-emr-assembl‌​y-0.0.0.jar
```

As you can see executing `echo $example` results in `echo MY-PROJECT`, but executing `echo $version` results in `echo '0.0.0'`. If I just hardcode the version to:
`version="2.11"` then the result would be this:

```
+ echo MY-PROJECT 
MY-PROJECT 
+ echo 0.0.0
0.0.0 
+ echo s3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jar
s3://here-avf-shared/emr_test/tiledgeo-validator-emr-assembl‌​y-0.0.0.jar
```

Note that there are no single quotes around `0.0.0`! I don't know why that is. Maybe it is because I assign result of `sed` and `cut` to the `version` variable, which makes it behave differently..

**EDIT 2**

Gordon Davisson was right that there was something else in `version` variable.

```
++ sbt version
++ sed -n '/MY-PROJECT\/\*:version/{n;p;}'
++ cut -f 2
+ version='0.0.0'
+ echo '<0.0.0>'
+ LC_ALL=C
+ cat -vt
<0.0.0^[[0m>
```

Comment: When you say it worked from command-line, did you run it as `aws s3 cp '/target/scala-2.11/MY-PROJECT-test-assembly-0.0.0.jar' 's3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jar'` or `aws s3 cp /target/scala-2.11/$example-test-assembly-$version.jar ${JAR_S3_PATH}`

Comment: Both worked from command line.

Comment: In `bash`, text that is surrounded by single quotes will not be expanded. If you have `testvar=5`, and you type `echo $testvar` you will get `5`, but if you type `echo '$testvar'`, you will get `$testvar`.

Comment: In your script, can you give us the outputs of `echo ${example}`, `echo ${version}`, and `echo ${JAR_S3_PATH}`?

Comment: This is run by the script (Note there is `set -x` set):

`+ echo MY-PROJECT`
`MY-PROJECT`
`+ echo '0.0.0'`
`0.0.0`
`+ echo 's3://BUCKET/TEST/MY-PROJECT-test-0.0.0.jarr'`
`s3://here-avf-shared/emr_test/tiledgeo-validator-emr-assembly-0.0.0.jar`

Comment: @ThomasKühn I know that, but how does that relate to my problem? There is no variable with single quotes in my script into which I want to inject any other `$var` to be expanded. version is the variable with single quotes and it only contains `0.0.0` and no variables to be expanded.

Comment: @koleS apparently I slightly misunderstood the part of your question where you ask "Why it doesn't work with the single quotes?"

Comment: @koleS, your script has `example="MY-PROEJCT"`, is that a typo just in the script or in the actual question? Are you sure the `version` variable contains those quotes? Your second-to-last code block doesn't seem to show them, just `0.0.0`. And `echo $version` should show them too. Though if there's some other weirdness inside the variables, `printf "%q" "$version"` would show them better than just `echo`. (Or `echo "${version@Q}"` in Bash 4.4)

Comment: Ok, if you just think, that you have quotes in `version` that you want gone, see if `version=$(echo $version | sed -e "s/'//g")` helps.

Comment: If `set -x` is printing `+ echo '0.0.0'`, that pretty much means there's some invisible character(s) in the variable -- if it were just "0.0.0", it wouldn't bother with the single-quotes. Try using `echo "<$version>" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` to see what's hiding there.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that there is something at the end of the variable. Please see the updated question..